# Move data/data files in Kotlin

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, file, kotlin

Im making an app for editing system files (data/data folder). I know that app needs root permission. How can I move files from one data/data folder to other. I thought that it would be easier to make when executing bash command.

Also maybe you have some useful info or documentation for building apps with root

I tried this

```
    but.setOnClickListener {
        root
        var testName = "bruh.txt"
        var text = "Help me"
        File( filesDir , testName).writeText(text)

        var dstString = "/data/data/com.test.testinproj/code_cache/"
        var srcString = "/data/data/com.test.testinproj/files/bruh.txt"

        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mv \"$srcString\" \"$dstString\"")
```

I expected that it will create file called bruh.txt in filesDir, and will move it to directory i need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy files in Kotlin without making an operating system exec call.

```kotlin
File(srcString).copyTo(
    target = File(dstString, "bruh.txt")
)
```

You can also [copy files recursively](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/copy-recursively.html), which may be easier, if you have multiple files to deal with.

If you need to make sure the destination file and directory is writable:

```kotlin
val destFile = File(dst, "bruh.txt").apply {
    if (!parentFile.canWrite()) {
        throw IOException("cannot write to $parent")
    } else if (exists() && !canWrite()) {
        throw IOException("cannot write to ${this.absolutePath}")
    }
}

File(srcString).copyTo(
    target = destFile
)
```

Comment: It worked, but if i need to copy file to other directory (for example /data/data/test/), the whole app crashes, maybge i need some root read/write permission?
I created test directory before*

Comment: @GzT you need to make sure you have write permission on the target dir. I'll update my answer with how to do so.

Comment: okay, im waiting, thx